# Applying where on ObservableCollection doesn't reflect on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection

I try to "filter" an ObservableCollection and update the bound DataGrid.

```
 ObservableCollection<Record> recordObservableCollection;
recordObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Record>(GetData()); //GetData() returns  IEnumerable<Record>

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = recordObservableCollection;
```

Then I try to filter this collection:

```
 recordObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Record>(recordObservableCollection.Where(filter));//filter is Func<Data.Record, bool>
```

`recordObservableCollection` is updated fine.

But the DataGrid is not updated.

Answer (score 4):

Your field or variable called `recordObservableCollection` has one value initially and a different value after filtering.  Because you used `new ObservableCollection<Record>(...)` twice you created two separate observable collection instances.

The problem is that the `DataGrid` is **still referring to the first instance**.  Even though you have changed `recordObservableCollection`, that only affects **its** value.  The value of `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is **still what it was before the filtering**.

To fix this problem, you need to re-assign the new collection's value to the `ItemSource` property.  Simply repeat what you did the first time, but **after** the filtering:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = recordObservableCollection;
```

and now `ItemSource` will be set to the new value of `recordObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Expose the `ObservableCollection<Record>` as a public property

also

Using `ObservableCollection` only affect binding when you add/remove items from your list. By using `ObservableCollection` you do not need to reset binding to the list or `DataGrid` when your collection changed (not the item inside collection changed). But they do not have any effect when your data object properties changed. For that you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your DataObject.

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection  will get update because  ObservableCollection (System.Collections.ObjectModel) throws an event every time the collection get changed but you have to set the filter collection as itemsource again other wise it wont update the UI...

The best way to do this use a public property that you'll bind in control as item source and in that property you will define **NotifyPropertyChanged**  in setter . Every time you'll change the collection using this property the control will also be updated ...

Let Suppose you have your data grid in test.xaml

--> First fo all work for INotifyPropertyChanged add an abstract class in your project inherit it from INotifyPropertyChanged interface and define OnPropertyChanged method

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

--> After add a class in your project named it testViewModel which will inherit your ViewModelBase Class..

--> Now in testViewModel  you'll make a property for your grid binding like this

```
  Private ObservableCollection<Record> _recordObservableCollection
  public  ObservableCollection<Record> recordObservableCollection
  {
  get
  {
       if(_recordObservableCollection == null)
        {
         _recordObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Record>(GetData());
         recordObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Record>(recordObservableCollection.Where(filter));
        }
       return _recordObservableCollection;
  }
 Set
  {

     _recordObservableCollection = Value;
      OnPropertyChanged("recordObservableCollection"); //Your property name 
  }
```

}

here now if u update your collection using property on any other property, method or command UI will be updated beacsue in setter you have defined OnPropertyChanged...

Now comes back to test.xaml here you have to do two things

1. Set dataContext of test.xaml either in code behing or in in xaml
   (In Code behind just after InitializeComponent() make an intance of viewmodel class and assign it as DataContext like this

   ```
     public test()
       {
       InitializeComponent();

       testViewModel  vm = new testViewModel();
       this.DataContext = vm;
       }
   ```
2. Bind property you defined in testViewModel  to grid

   ```
    <Grid Name="MyGrid" DataContext="{Binding recordObservableCollection}">
     </Grid>
   ```

Comment: I am not sure I understand, I should create public ObservableCollection<Record> RcordObservableCollection property, and inside setter{} define what?

Comment: Working with wpf the best way is to use MVVM pattern in this property is the deriving wheel of data ..ok i am updating my post hope tou'll understand what am i saying..